# Is this consider business logic flaw or improper validation?

Tags: penetration-testing

I am currently testing a web application as a pentest project and i found an API handling authorization code does not properly verify if a user is registered in the application. I was able to intercept the response page, change a parameter name "isnewUser" to true (default is false if wrong authorization code provide) and input any authorization code and i am able to get in the application. Although it's main login is handle by Okta, but the app itself require this auth code before displaying the home page. My question is, what vulnerability should this be considered? Calling it business logic flaw sounds like abit off given you need to intercept the raw request to be able to trigger the flaw and improper validation seems like more on the bet as it does not verify if the auth code is registered in the application. Sample code:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 ok
Host: example.com
Content-type: application/json

{"authorizationCode":"test", "isnewUser":"true"}
```